# vb.net Procedure or function expects parameter, which was not supplied

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am receiving this error:

```
Procedure or function 'usp__SingleSelectServerRackName' expects parameter '@chvServerName', which was not supplied.
```

I looked up the error and did not find any applicable solutions.
I was successfully able to run the Proc and retrieve out put information, and was able to successfully retrieve value of `cbserver.valuemember` in command window.

Any suggestions to correct this problem?

Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

    Try

        Dim connString As String = "server=ServerName;database=DatabaseName;trusted_connection=yes"

        Using connection As New SqlConnection(connString)

            'Create the command and set its properties.
            Dim SingleSelectServerRackName As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
            SingleSelectServerRackName.Connection = connection
            SingleSelectServerRackName.CommandText = "usp__SingleSelectServerRackName"
            SingleSelectServerRackName.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure


            'Add the input parameter and set its properties
            Dim ParamSingleSelectServerName As New SqlParameter()
            ParamSingleSelectServerName.ParameterName = "@chvServerName"
            ParamSingleSelectServerName.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar
            ParamSingleSelectServerName.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            ParamSingleSelectServerName.Value = cbServer.SelectedValue.ToString()

            Dim ParamSingleSelectServerRackName As New SqlParameter
            ParamSingleSelectServerName.ParameterName = "@numServerRackName"
            ParamSingleSelectServerRackName.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar
            ParamSingleSelectServerRackName.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            ParamSingleSelectServerRackName.Size = 50

            'Add the parameters to the Parameters collection
            SingleSelectServerRackName.Parameters.Add(ParamSingleSelectServerName)
            SingleSelectServerRackName.Parameters.Add(ParamSingleSelectServerRackName)

    'Open database connection
            connection.Open()

            'Execute data reader
            Dim readerSingleSelectServerRackName As SqlDataReader = SingleSelectServerRackName.ExecuteReader()
            readerSingleSelectServerRackName.Close()

            cbRackName.ValueMember = SingleSelectServerRackName.Parameters("@numServerRackName").Value.ToString

            'Close database connection
            connection.Close()

        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        MsgBox(ex.StackTrace)

    End Try
```

Proc:

```
CREATE Procedure usp__SingleSelectServerRackName
(
@chvServerName AS varchar(50),      ---Input variable @chvServerName displays 
@numServerRackName AS varchar(50) OUTPUT    ---Output variable @numServerRackName
)
AS Begin

IF @chvServerName is null or len(ltrim(@chvServerName)) = 0     ---Check for null value
    RAISERROR('Servername cannot be blank.',16,1)

SELECT Rcknm.nm
FROM Rcknm
INNER JOIN Srvr
    on srvr.fk_rcknm = Rcknm.ID
WHERE srvr.nm = @chvServerName  
End
```

Comment: It might be simpler to not use an OUTPUT parameter and use [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the value.

Comment: Could you show me how I could use ExecuteScalar to pull the output parameter from my stored procedure?

Comment: I think the example in the documentation I linked to says it all. You just don't need to use an output parameter at all.

Comment: Thanks for all of your comments and help, unfortunately; I was not knowledgeable enough to make good use of the advice that I was given. I resolved the problem by using the With statement and passed the values directly to the combo box as a value.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missed something on your copy/paste of parameters.

```
ParamSingleSelectServerName.ParameterName = "@numServerRackName"

ParamSingleSelectServerName.ParameterName = "@chvServerName"
```

Your second parameter is overwriting your first. Try this instead.

```
 ParamSingleSelectServerRackName.ParameterName = "@numServerRackName"
```

Comment: There was a mistype in the code. Replaced it; however the same error is present.

Comment: I think you're missing something then.  I just copy pasted your code, changed the connection string, removed the lines related to your controls and stored procedure content, and I got no errors.  
It may have something to do with this line `cbRackName.ValueMember = SingleSelectServerRackName.Parameters("@numServerRackName").Value.ToString`  You're not returning anything from your stored procedure for this output parameter.

Comment: I'm sure I am missing something. Is there a better way to return the output parameter or a way to correct the code I have written so that it does if this is the problem?

Comment: Right now, your @numServerRackName in the line I mentioned above is DBNull.Value.  For one, you can change your query to set the value.

'SELECT TOP 1 @numServerRackName = Rcknm.nm
FROM Rcknm
INNER JOIN Srvr
    on srvr.fk_rcknm = Rcknm.ID
WHERE srvr.nm = @chvServerName'

Next, since you're not returning a recordset, there's no reason to call `SingleSelectServerRackName.ExecuteReader()`  Instead, try `SingleSelectServerRackName.ExecuteNonQuery()`  Then, you don't need `readerSingleSelectServerRackName` anymore.

Comment: I made the changes to the procedure and used ExecuteNonQuery(), but was still unable to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Name of the 2nd parameter is same so overwriting it

Comment: There was a mistype in the code. Replaced it; however the same error is present

Answer (score 0):

Look at these two lines

```
Dim ParamSingleSelectServerRackName As New SqlParameter
ParamSingleSelectServerName.ParameterName = "@numServerRackName"
```

You are declaring the second parameter, but then you set the name intended for the second parameter to the first parameter.
That's the missing parameter, you have no more a parameter called `@chvServerName`

You are really making your life difficult. Why not just calling the twos @Rack and @Server ?

Comment: I corrected the typo in my code; however the same error message is displayed.